# Share Image on twitter using JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, share

I need to share image on twitter by JavaScript and HTML. I am using below code and its working but ts showing as a link not image. I don't want to create developer application and direct share hard-coded image on twitter.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=https://i.picsum.photos/id/313/200/300.jpg?hmac=7_pHHv7TyDti50LaIVPvCPkdWDgM0tcX3ViCIWruEDQ&text=This is twitter share"  target="_blank">              
    <img class="shareUlLi" id="shareTwitter" src="./images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter Share" title="Twitter Share"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are really two approaches here:

- use the Twitter Web Share intent (this is what you are doing here). The Share intent does not support uploading images, so all you can do is include a link a web site where the image is hosted. If the site implements a Twitter card, you could have an image show as part of the card (for example, a Summary Large Image card)
- create a Twitter app, have the user authenticate to it, have them select an image to upload (or upload on their behalf) using the Twitter media upload API, and then post a Tweet programmatically with that image attached.